# Shopware administration module not showing up after administration:build

Tags: javascript, shopware

I'm building a Shopware plugin with part storefront and part administration. The storefront part is working fine, but I can't get the administration part to show up in the menu on the admin page with the administration:build command.

I followed the Shopware Docs and the Shopware course on how to do this. I matched them both but still no success. Might there be something I'm missing here?

**This is the main.js file where I import the plugin folder.**

```js
import './module/configurator';
```

**This is the index.js file in the plugin folder where I register my plugin**

```js
import './page/configurator-component-list';
import './page/configurator-component-detail';
import './page/configurator-component-create';

Shopware.Module.register('configurator', {
    type: 'plugin',
    name: 'Configurator',
    color: '#ff3d58',
    icon: 'default-shopping-paper-bag-product',
    title: 'Configurator',
    description: 'Module for registering components',

    routes: {
        index: {
            component: 'configurator-component-list',
            path: 'index'
        },
        detail: {
            component: 'configurator-component-detail',
            path: 'detail/:id',
            meta: {
                parentPath: 'configurator.index'
            }
        },
        create: {
            component: 'configurator-component-create',
            path: 'create',
            meta: {
                parentPath: 'configurator.index'
            }
        }
    },

    navigation: [{
        label: 'Configurator',
        color: '#ff3d58',
        path: 'configurator.index',
        icon: 'default-shopping-paper-bag-product',
        parent: 'sw-catalogue',
        position: 100
    }],
});
```

**And just in case there might be something wrong with my file tree, here it is**

```
- administration
  - src
    - module
      - configurator
        - page (includes the different components of the plugin)
        - index.js
    - main.js
- storefront
  - src
```

**Output of administration:build**

```
Starting Execution of 'administration:build' ('/var/www/html/dev-ops/administration/actions/build.sh')


(1/3) Starting
> bin/console bundle:dump
    Cannot load Xdebug - it was already loaded
    
     [OK] Dumped plugin configuration.                                              
    
    
(2/3) Starting
> PROJECT_ROOT=/var/www/html ENV_FILE=/var/www/html/.env npm run --prefix vendor/shopware/platform/src/Administration/Resources/app/administration/ build
    
    > administration@1.0.0 build /var/www/html/vendor/shopware/platform/src/Administration/Resources/app/administration
    > mode=production webpack
    
    # Compiling with Webpack configuration
    # Production mode is activated 
    # Plugin "Storefront": Injected successfully
    # Plugin "PCvue": Injected successfully

    Time: 50301ms

    Entrypoint commons = static/js/runtime.js static/css/vendors-node.css static/js/vendors-node.js static/js/vendors-node.js.map static/js/commons.js
    Entrypoint app = static/js/runtime.js static/css/vendors-node.css static/js/vendors-node.js static/js/vendors-node.js.map static/css/app.css static/js/app.js
    Entrypoint storefront = static/js/runtime.js static/css/vendors-node.css static/js/vendors-node.js static/js/vendors-node.js.map static/css/storefront.css static/js/storefront.js
    Entrypoint p-cvue = static/js/runtime.js static/js/p-cvue.js
       3847 modules
    
(3/3) Starting
> bin/console assets:install
    Cannot load Xdebug - it was already loaded
    Copying files for bundle: FrameworkBundle
    Copying files for bundle: MonologBundle
    Copying files for bundle: SwiftmailerBundle
    Copying files for bundle: SensioFrameworkExtraBundle
    Copying files for bundle: TwigBundle
    Copying files for bundle: WebProfilerBundle
    Copying files for bundle: DebugBundle
    Copying files for bundle: EnqueueBundle
    Copying files for bundle: EnqueueAdapterBundle
    Copying files for bundle: Framework
    Copying files for bundle: System
    Copying files for bundle: Content
    Copying files for bundle: Checkout
    Copying files for bundle: Profiling
    Copying files for bundle: Administration
    Copying files for bundle: Docs
    Copying files for bundle: Storefront
    Copying files for bundle: Elasticsearch
    Copying files for bundle: PCvue
    Copying files for bundle: DbalKernelPluginLoader
    
     [OK] Successfully copied all bundle files                                      
    
    
Duration: 1m 1s
All commands successfully executed!
```

Answer (score 5):

I Finally(!!) found the problem. For anyone wondering what the problem was.

In the index.js you need to add snippets:

```js
snippets: {
    'de-DE': deDE,
    'en-GB': enGB
},
```

I had this before, but since I wasn't using snippets yet I removed them. But here's the catch.
They can't just contain `{ }`
They need to atleast contain the plugin name

```js
{
    'plugin-name': {

    }
}
```

Without them it won't install properly, so it won't show up in the menu. Luckily they don't give you an error message explaining everything ;)

Answer (score 3):

I think your `main.js` should go in the folder `src`

https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/administration/add-custom-module#creating-the-index-js-file

Comment: Oh whoops it is in that folder, but I recreated my file tree wrong. Edited it now

Comment: Do you see that your module gets injected when running the administration:build command? 
And just to be sure: Shopware Plugin is installed and activated?

Comment: What I see that gets injected is the complete plugin, nothing specific about the storefront part or the administration part of the plugin. And it is installed and activated. The storefront part is working without problems

Comment: I added the log of administration:build to the question. Name of the plugin is PCvue

Comment: hmm you're right, it gets injected successfully, so we can rule this out at least. I don't see anything obvious here, I'm sorry

Answer (score 1):

The Module name must be (vendor)-(modul)

```js
Shopware.Module.register('vendor-configurator', {
}
```

Took me hours to find out!

Comment: This was also the problem in my case. In my experience, there is a fairly long list of things that needs to be done right just to have an admin- entry show up. E.g:

 file tree needs to be accurate
; component name needs to be `vendor-optional-optional2`
; `routes.index.component` needs to match `vendor-optional-optional2`
; `group` in `settingsItem` should be `plugins` and not "plugin", as is erroneously mentioned many places.

AND, that is just a few of the things we need. It is super convoluted!